# add measure time of code to list and get min/ max/ mid / avg times

Tags: java

I want to test my code timing and to get the min / max / avg / mid time of code,
so I use the StopWatch as so:

```
List<StopWatch> list = new ArrayList()<>;
stopwatch.start();
code
StopWatch passTime = stopwatch.stop();
list.add(passTime)
```

I want to get the times as double so I can use the min, max avg mid functions of list, is there way to do it? or even better solution?
Thanks

Comment: You should look at using Micrometer/Dropwizard metric Gauges

Comment: Why ? what is wrong with the current solution?

Comment: Well, because those automatically publish min/max and average statistics

Comment: its for java or spring?

Comment: Both? You don't need a specific framework to use metrics libraries

Comment: interest, I didn't know it, can you write small example on my case? thanks

Comment: @ness - There should be examples in the documentation for the libraries.  Did you look?

Comment: yes but looking for something to my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stream the list and gather [summary statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html). Here is an example using a stream of Integers.  There are also summarizing collectors for `double` and `long` too.

```
List<Integer> list =
                new ArrayList<>(List.of(10, 20, 30, 40, 50));
        
IntSummaryStatistics iss = list.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue));
System.out.println(iss);
```

Prints

```
IntSummaryStatistics{count=5, sum=150, min=10, average=30.000000, max=50}
```

Each value may be accessed separately via a getter. Note: that the collectors take a `ToType function` to get the field on which to compute the statistics.  So you would need something like `StopWatch::getTime` or whatever makes sense.

Comment: these is the problem that the StopWatch doesn't have something like that, you have any idea of how to get the Double on it?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with that class.  I would have to see the API for it. But if you can't get a value how does one use it?

Comment: you can by write
`StopWatch passTime = stopwatch.stop();
or by
StopWatch passTime = stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
where the interest idea is that you actualy don't need to write `TimeUnit.SECONDS` because it knows to measure even less than sec or more than sec and than the output will be calculate exactly for what needs

Comment: Then perhaps you need to put each lap in a `List` of the appropriate type (double or long) and then use that list to compute the statistics.  From where did you get/import the class?

Comment: Indeed, each loop I put the results in a List, probably it will be of Doubles, and than I don't find the same option to calculate the doubles, 
The class is from [here](https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html)

Comment: Try this. `LongSummaryStatistics iss = list.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingLong(sw->sw.elapsed(TimeUnit.SECONDS)));` after you create your list of StopWatch intervals.

Comment: I did these :
`DoubleSummaryStatistics iss = timeList.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Double::doubleValue));`
Looks that worked, what is that `sw->sw` in your example?

Comment: It's a lambda expression.  It says, for each list entry sw (StopWatch in your )case, envoke the method sw.elapsed(..).  I highly recommend you read about lambdas and method references. They are discussed in the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).   And don't forget to read about the summary statistics.  You can grab each value separately via the getters.

Comment: I know them but I wanted to know why to force it to be SECONDS, yes it can be that it will be less than sec but..If I put it in list of doubles so I will get zeros instead to fill the template, isn't it?

Comment: I just used that as an example.  You will need to read the documentation for other units.